# Domain not L-domain

Tags: order-theory, domain-theory

I'm looking for an example of a domain(continuos dcpo) which isn't an L-domain(every principal ideal is a complete lattice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this one:

[image]

The principal ideal $\mathord\downarrow \{a\}$ is not a complete lattice, as the subset $\{d,e\}$ has no supremum. It is a dcpo, since any directed set that does not contain $a$ must also not contain $b$ or not contain $c$.

Comment: Good, thanks. Another question: a domain, not L- Domain, in which every principal ideal is a join-semilattice.